# Is it on or off topic to ask questions about TOGAF usage here?

Tags: discussion

[Togaf](http://www.opengroup.org/subjectareas/enterprise/togaf/) (The open group architecture framework) is an enterprise achitecture practice / modelling framework.  For people using it it can be tricky to understand and know the subtlities of what to apply where. Assuming the questions are specific and answerable Is asking question about how to use the framework off topic for this exchange?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it meets the other criteria for being a good question, it would be on-topic as a [software architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_architecture) or [software design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design) question. If you want to share some specific questions that you had in mind in advance, you can do it, but questions about applying TOGAF (or other enterprise architectural frameworks) are on-topic.